# Using Wildfly 10 with Let's Encrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, jboss, lets-encrypt

I am thinking about a change to Let's Encrypt certificates for my WildFly 10 HTTPS connections.

But I am a bit anxious about the needed automatically restart of Wildlfy after the scheduled import by the certbot and the import of the new certificate into the keystore.

On the other hand I am using Let's Encrypt certificates with nginx without Problems for a while so my first thought is using nginx as HTTPS Proxy for the Wildlfy server. A nginx restarts in less than a second, for comparison the Wildfly takes up to 60 seconds to restart.

What speaks against using nginx as HTTPS proxy for a Wildfly server to prevent restarts or is it possible to replace the certificate in a keystore without restarting the Application server?

Comment: Single node? Nginx infront if every site for SSL termination and provide a friendly error when the backend does have issues is never a bad idea imho